# Filtering array on multiple options to return options in new select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am supporting some legacy code and having some issues in implementing a new feature.

I have 2 multiple select options, first one showing a list of states, second showing a list of cities. The idea is that the list of cities will be filtered dependant on the selected states in the first select.

Currently the cities are contained in a javascript array which is used in an if statement to attach the relevant options to the select, howeber this only works on a single state selection.

How can I filter the cities on multiple state selections?

I have tried numerous if statement combinations with no luck. My jquery knowledge is obviously lacking and haven't found anything similar in google/stackoverflow - however I appreciate I may be approaching this from the wrong angle.

```
<form name="newform">
<select multiple size="10" name="getStateSelect" id="getStateSelectID" onchange="GetSeries(document.newform.getStateSelect.options [document.newform.getStateSelect.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="1">Alaska</option>
    <option value="2">Arizona</option>
    <option value="3">Californa</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<select id="getCitySelect" multiple="multiple" size="10"></select>
</form>


var fsArray = [{id: 1,stateid: 1,cityname: "Anchorage"}, 
    {id: 2,stateid: 1,cityname: "Fairbanks"}, 
    {id: 3,stateid: 1,cityname: "Wasilla"}, 
    {id: 4,stateid: 2,cityname: "Flagstaff"}, 
    {id: 5,stateid: 2,cityname: "Phoenix"}, 
    {id: 6,stateid: 2,cityname: "Tucson"}, 
    {id: 7,stateid: 3,cityname: "Fremont"}, 
    {id: 8,stateid: 3,cityname: "Lakeport"}, 
    {id: 9,stateid: 3,cityname: "Los Angeles"}];

function GetSeries(i) {
var SeriesSelectBox = document.getElementById("getCitySelect");
SeriesSelectBox.options.length = 0;

for (j in fsArray) {
    if (fsArray[j].stateid == i) {
        var seriesLength = SeriesSelectBox.options.length;
        SeriesSelectBox.options[seriesLength] = new Option(fsArray[j].cityname, fsArray[j].id);
    }
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fcp3h7mw/1/

Any help greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added a for loop on the getStateSelectID values to check if each element for selection status, if selected it runs your loop to add the cities.

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fcp3h7mw/5/

javascript:

```
var fsArray = [
    {id:1,stateid:1,cityname:"Anchorage"},
    {id:2,stateid:1,cityname:"Fairbanks"},
    {id:3,stateid:1,cityname:"Wasilla"},
    {id:4,stateid:2,cityname:"Flagstaff"},
    {id:5,stateid:2,cityname:"Phoenix"},
    {id:6,stateid:2,cityname:"Tucson"},
    {id:7,stateid:3,cityname:"Fremont"},
    {id:8,stateid:3,cityname:"Lakeport"},
    {id:9,stateid:3,cityname:"Los Angeles"}
];

function GetSeries(i) {     
    var id = document.getElementById("getStateSelectID");
    var SeriesSelectBox = document.getElementById("getCitySelect");
    SeriesSelectBox.options.length = 0;     
    var states = 0;

    for (states=0; states < id.length; states++) {
        if(id[states].selected){
            for (j in fsArray) {
                if (fsArray[j].stateid == id[states].value) {
                    var seriesLength = SeriesSelectBox.options.length;
                    SeriesSelectBox.options[seriesLength] = new Option(fsArray[j].cityname, fsArray[j].id);     
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Markup: I also took out a lot of your function call in the markup

```
<select multiple size="10" name="getStateSelect" id="getStateSelectID" onchange="GetSeries();">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, they both resolve the issue I was having. I have selected this answer as most helpful as it requires the least amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code to be able to select multiple states and display the correct cities.

Essentially, you needed to get a list of options with attribute "selected" and store the option values in an array (onchange)

Afterwards, you would iterate through the new array and match against the values in the array instead of a single value.

Here's the updated code:  http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/fcp3h7mw/3/

```
var fsArray = [
    {id:1,stateid:1,cityname:"Anchorage"},
    {id:2,stateid:1,cityname:"Fairbanks"},
    {id:3,stateid:1,cityname:"Wasilla"},
    {id:4,stateid:2,cityname:"Flagstaff"},
    {id:5,stateid:2,cityname:"Phoenix"},
    {id:6,stateid:2,cityname:"Tucson"},
    {id:7,stateid:3,cityname:"Fremont"},
    {id:8,stateid:3,cityname:"Lakeport"},
    {id:9,stateid:3,cityname:"Los Angeles"}
];

function getSeries() {      
    var SeriesSelectBox = document.getElementById("getCitySelect");
    SeriesSelectBox.options.length = 0;     

    var arr = getStateSelected();

    for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {

        for (var j in fsArray) {
            if (fsArray[j].stateid == arr[i]) {
                var seriesLength = SeriesSelectBox.options.length;
                SeriesSelectBox.options[seriesLength] = new Option(fsArray[j].cityname, fsArray[j].id);     
          }
        }
    }
}

function getStateSelected() {
    var sel = document.querySelectorAll('#getStateSelectID option');
    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i< sel.length; i++ ) {
        if ( sel[i].selected ) {
          arr.push(sel[i].value);   
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you have questions.